# SQLAlchemy + MariaDB: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I know this question has been asked before but I cannot get it to work. I'm writing an app to scrap some stock information on the web. The scraping part takes about 70 minutes to complete where I pass my SQLAlchemy objects into a function.
After the function completes it is supposed to insert the data into the data to the database and this is when I get the error. I guess MariaDB have closed the session then?

Code:

```
    with get_session() as session:
        stocks = session.query(Stock).filter(or_(Stock.market.like('%Large%'), Stock.market.like("%First North%"))).all()
        for stock, path in chrome.download_stock(stocks=stocks): # This function takes about 70 minutes, not using any session in here, only Stock objects
            # Starting to insert and get the error on the first insert
```

Error:
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

get_session() function:

```
@contextmanager
def get_session(debug=False):
    engine = create_engine('mysql://root:pw@IP/DB', echo=debug, encoding='utf8', pool_recycle=300, pool_pre_ping=True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

I have tried to decrease the pool_recycle to 300 seconds and add the new pool_pre_ping that came with SQLAlchemny 1.2 but nothing works. Any ideas? You think it is in the code or on the server side?

MariaDB: 10.2.14

SQLAlchemy: 1.2.7

EDIT:
Started to investigate MariaDB wait_timeout because of FrankerZ's comment with some interesting result, first from mysql-command:

```
SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| wait_timeout  | 28800 |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then through Python / SQLAlchemy:

```
print(session.execute("SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';").first())
('wait_timeout', '600')
```

Any explanation for this? Should be the problem right?

Comment: You need to update mysql's keepalive timeout (This has nothing to do with SQLAlchemy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 "wait_timeouts"; it is quite confusing.

Right after connecting, do

```
SET SESSION wait_timeout=12000
```

That will give you 200 minutes.

Also make sure SQLAlchemy does not have a timeout.  (PHP, for example, does.)

Comment: Added     session.execute("SET wait_timeout=28800") to my get_sessions command and it now works